# Using SQL Not exists in LOV in Apex 4.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, lov

I'm having trouble with the following sql query

```
select sr.rekeningnummer display_value, sr.rekeningnummer return_value
from  studentenrekening sr
where not exists (SELECT *
                   FROM   studentenkredietrekening skr
                   WHERE  sr.rekeningnummer = skr.rekeningnummer);
```

*(rekeningnummer is account number in english and studentenkredietrekeningnummer is creditcard number in english)*

I'm having a list of values in a form in apex 4.0 which should contain the values of a account number which doesn't have a creditcard yet.

When I put the sql in the LOV  list,
I'm getting the following error:
1 error has occurred
Failed to parse LOV SQL query!
ORA-00911: invalid character

What's wrong with my query? When I run it in SQL Developer it does give me the right account numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove that **semicolon** at the end of the statement.

```
select sr.rekeningnummer display_value, sr.rekeningnummer return_value
from  studentenrekening sr
where not exists (SELECT *
               FROM   studentenkredietrekening skr
               WHERE  sr.rekeningnummer = skr.rekeningnummer)
```